# Getting selected node index on TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get exact index number of selected node.

I use below code however , it doesn't show the exact index.

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Index


a
 b
  c 
 d
  e
   f--> If i click on 'f' i want to get '6' value
```

How can i get index of the selected node on treeview?

Comment: What's the index on a hierarchy?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti didn't get your question.

Comment: what does treeView1.SelectedNode.Index show you and what you are expecting to see ?

Comment: @C.Dhruv edited.

Comment: What value you are getting for `treeView1.SelectedNode.Index` right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know, the TreeView control is a hierarchical collection of TreeNodes where each TreeNode may have a List of child TreeNodes.  The Index property of a TreeNode is it's (zero based) index in the collection of sibling TreeNodes.  So in your example above, TreeNode 'f' if selected, will return an Index value of 0, because it is the first TreeNode at that level.  If I were to draw your example tree with each nodes corresponding index, you would see something like this:

```
a 0
 b 0
  c 0
 d 1  <-- because 'd' is the second node at this level. 'b' is index 0
  e 0
   f 0
```

Now, to answer your question, you will need to rely on `recursion`.  If you are't familiar with this concept, see `recursion`.  All kidding aside, it simply means a function that calls itself.  Why do we need recursion to answer this question?  Because we don't know how many elements are in the tree above the currently selected node, and so we will need to count as we move up the tree hierarchy.

First lesson in writing a recursive function: make a way for it to exit.  Unlike an infinite loop, recursion cannot go on forever or you will get a stack overflow exception (not to be confused with this site).

The second thing to note about a recursive function is that it will be mind bendingly simple.

So what you are wanting is something like this:

```
a 0
 b 1
  c 2
 d 3
  e 4
   f 5
```

Now, I know you said that you wanted it to return 6, not 5, but in most modern languages indexes start at 0, not 1.

OK, so if we start with a simple recursive function that crawls up the tree we will have something like this:

```
private int GetIndex(TreeNode node)
{
    // Always make a way to exit the recursion.
    if (node.Parent == null)
        return node.Index;

    return node.Index + GetIndex(node.Parent);
}
```

Now the above code will recurse up the tree, but it wont give us the correct answer.  Why?  Because if the TreeNode that we are evaluating has siblings higher in the index (Node 'b' to node 'd' in your example), we are missing the child nodes.  And because child nodes can have child nodes (on and on...) we have another recursive function.

Recursion round 2:

```
private int GetIndex(TreeNode node)
{
    int returnValue = 0;

    // Always make a way to exit the recursion.
    if (node.Index == 0 && node.Parent == null)
        return returnValue;

    // Now, count every node.
    returnValue = 1;

    // If I have siblings higher in the index, then count them and their decendants.
    if (node.Index > 0)
    {
        TreeNode previousSibling = node.PrevNode;
        while (previousSibling != null)
        {
            returnValue += GetDecendantCount(previousSibling);
            previousSibling = previousSibling.PrevNode;
        }
    }

    if (node.Parent == null)
        return returnValue;
    else
        return returnValue + GetIndex(node.Parent);
}

public int GetDecendantCount(TreeNode node)
{
    int returnValue = 0;

    // If the node is not the root node, then we want to count it.
    if (node.Index != 0 || node.Parent != null)
        returnValue = 1;

    // Always make a way to exit a recursive function.
    if (node.Nodes.Count == 0)
        return returnValue;

    foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
    {
        returnValue += GetDecendantCount(childNode);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

And that should do what you are asking.

Comment: nicely explained !